# Атрибут Header работает не корректно

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я использую [Header(string title)] перед переменной для отображения названия title в инспекторе, однако результат не очень корректный:

```
[Header("Bar Color")][SerializeField] private Color barColor;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Результат очень даже корректный.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Почему же тогда название отображается дважды?

Comment: Сверху "жирным" - параметр из атрибута. То, что ниже - "стандартное Unity преобразование" имени поля. Назовите поле "_barColor" и результат будет такой же. Назовите "colorBar" и в инспекторе увидите "Color Bar"

Comment: Результат в инспекторе полностью соответствует тому, как должно быть. В 99.99%, когда программист говорит, что программа работает неправильно, это ошибка программиста. Просто Юнити умеет имя переменной (barColor) преобразовывать так, чтобы оно красивее смотрелось в инспекторе, а точнее разбивает имя переменной пробелами перед заглавными буквами, переводит первую букву в регистр, удаляет некоторые небуквенные символы... 'barColor' –> ’BarColor’

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[InspectorName(string title)] решил мою проблему. Не понимаю, почему данного синтаксиса не было в документации. Хорошо что в VS есть подсказки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во первых это документация какой версии? все там есть! Во вторых в чем не корректность? Header это заголовок!